# Generic extends a union who contains an assignment?

Tags: typescript

I've seen this pattern and I don't understand what is going on.

```
interface Foo<T extends string | string[] = string | string[]> { }
```

I have an interface with a generic that extends three items. The second item contains an assignment where a string array is assigned to a string?

I haven't been able to find an answer on the forums because I find this problem hard to articulate.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is confusing, and it is not a Union of 3 items.

In fact it just says `T extends string | string[]`, and the default type is `string | string[]` if T is not specified.

So `const foo: Foo` will be infer to `const foo: Foo<string | string[]>`

Here are some transformations to help you to understand what's happening.

1:

```
interface Foo<T extends (string | string[]) = (string | string[])> { }
```

2:

```
type StringOrArray = string | string[]
interface Foo<T extends StringOrArray = StringOrArray > { }
```